# Received an error message for the select option

Tags: php, forms, file, validation, select

I've received this error message:

Notice: Undefined variable: location1 in /home/students/accounts///www/htdocs/jobassign1b/jobsprocess.php on line 126

The error message, if you look at the php code below, it comes on this line

```
if (fwrite($jobTxt, $positionID . " " . $title . " " . $description . " " . $positionButton . " " . $contractButton . " " . $location1 . " " . $date . " " . $application . "\n"))
```

I've created a select field for location, and on the php, I need to validate and ensure that when user submit a form, the data goes to the file directory.

I am really stuck with this one and I've tried everything.
Any help would be greatly appreciate.

this is the code for the select field

```
<label for="location">Location:</label>
            <select name="location" form="locationform">
            <option value="---">---</option>
            <option value="act">ACT</option>
            <option value="nsw">NSW</option>
            <option value="nt">NT</option>
            <option value="qld">QLD</option>
            <option value="sa">SA</option>
            <option value="tas">TAS</option>
            <option value="vic">VIC</option>
            <option value="wa">WA</option>
            </select>
```

This is the code for the location part in php

```
<?php
//Opening, and creating a path for diretories to create
$newdir = "../../data/jobs2";
umask(0007);

$errors = array(); //sets an error array, this will append to an error string
$applicationArray = (isset($_POST['applicationby']) ? $_POST['applicationby'] : null); 


if (isset($_POST["positionid"])) 
{
    $positionID = $_POST["positionid"];         
    $patternID = "/^P[0-9]{4}$/";                       //This regex ensure that the first letter is start with P following number 0-9 in length of 4.                                                  
    if (preg_match($patternID, $positionID))        //check if the statuscode is matches with the regex
    {
        $ans = "";
        $length = strlen($positionID);
        echo $positionID . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "Please fill in Position ID as they are mandatory field");       //To ensure and detect if there is any error
}

if (isset ($_POST["title"])) 
{
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\s\.,!]{0, 20}*$/";         //This regex ensure that alphanumeric character, space, comma, period, and exclamation mark, other symbols or characters are not allowed and maximum of 20 alphanumeric characters.
    if (preg_match($pattern, $title))        //Check that the status if matches with the regex
    {
        echo $title . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please fill in Status as they are mandatory field!");
}

if (isset ($_POST["description"])) 
{
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $patternDescription = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._ \t]{1,260}$";       //This regex ensure that the description is set to maximum character is up to 260
    if (preg_match('/' . $patternDescription . '/', $description))       //Check that the description is matches with the regex
    {
            echo $description . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please fill in Description as they are mandatory field!");
}

if (isset ($_POST["position"]))         
{
    $positionButton = $_POST["position"];
    echo $positionButton . "<br />";
}
else
{
    //Not possible unless in exceptional circumstances
    array_push($errors, "Please choose the position");
}

if (isset ($_POST["contract"]))         
{
    $contractButton = $_POST["contract"];
    echo $contractButton . "<br />";
}
else
{
    //Not possible unless in exceptional circumstances
    array_push($errors, "Please choose the contract");
}

if (isset($_POST['location'])) 
{
    $location1 = $_POST['location'];
    echo $location1 . "<br />";
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "please choose the location");
}

if (isset($_POST["date"]))          
{
    // writing the date format
    $date = date("d/m/y");          
    echo $date . "<br />";
} else {
    //$date = $_POST["date"];
} 

if (isset($applicationArray)) 
{

    //Display no "array" name, by creating a new variable name
    foreach($applicationArray as $application)
    {
        echo $application . "<br />";
    }
}
//check if file exist
if(!file_exists($newdir)){
//create a directory
    mkdir($newdir, 02770);
}

$jobTxt = fopen($newdir. "/jobs2.txt", "a+");
// This is to ensure that the file is
if  (is_writeable($newdir. "/jobs2.txt")) {
    //write the following variable
    if (fwrite($jobTxt, $positionID . " " . $title . " " . $description . " " . $positionButton . " " . $contractButton . " " . $location1 . " " . $date . " " . $application . "\n"))
{
}
    echo "<p>Your form has succesfully been submit!</p>";
}
fclose($jobTxt);



if(isset($positionID, $title))
{
//Validation Check

    //Check if characters length is less or more than 5 characters
    if (0 === strlen($positionID > 5 || $positionID < 5)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Your characters length is either less or more than 5 characters<br/>");
    }



        //Check if characters length is less or more than 20 characters
    if (0 === strlen($title > 20)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Your characters length is more than 20 characters, the maximum number is 20 alphanumeric characters!<br/>");
    }



    //Check if Position ID is left not blank
    if (0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $positionID)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You forgot to fill in the Position ID!<br />");
    }



    //Check if Title is left not blank
    if (0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $title)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You forgot to fill in the Title! <br />");
    }


    //Check if user made a mistake with typo
    if (0 === preg_match($patternID, $positionID)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> please make sure that the first letter in Status Code is uppercase 'P' following by 4 numbers. <br />");
    }



    //Remind user to avoid the unnecessary symbol
    if (0 === preg_match($pattern, $title)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please make sure to avoid symbols other than \",.!\" <br />");
    }
}


if (isset($errors)) 
{
    //Display no array name by changing the variable
    foreach ($errors as $error) 
    {
        echo '<strong>', $error, '</strong>';
    }
}
//provide back to form page link
echo '<a href="jobpostform.php">Back to Form page.</a> <br />';
//provide back to home page link
echo '<a href="index.php">Back to Home page.</a>'; 



?>
```

Comment: If `$location1` is undefined, that means the the first few lines in your PHP snippet aren't executed - ie. `$_POST['location']` is not set. Can you post the rest of your code, as there may be other stuff interfering with the form submit.

Comment: I've posted the rest of the code, thanks for having a look at the code, im still trying to figuring it out whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Is location in `$_POST`? If not `location1` will not be defined.

You could add this adjustment:

```
$location1 = '---';
if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
    $location1 = $_POST['location'];
}
```

Which would ensure that the variable location1 is always defined and will mean you will no longer see the notice.

If the location is not being submitted with the form it could be down to your use of the `form` attribute on the select element.